# Relational Table PDO view all

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$member_id=$_GET['id']; // Collecting data from query string
if(!is_numeric($member_id)){ // Checking data it is a number or not
  echo "Data Error"; 
  exit;
}
$handler = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=manager', 'root', 'jordan31');
$count=$handler->prepare("select * from login, member_workouts where member_workouts.member_id=:member_id");
$count->bindParam(":member_id",$member_id,PDO::PARAM_INT,3);
if($count->execute())
  $row = $count->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
if( ! $row)
  print('No Workouts Found');
else 
  echo "<tr bgcolor='#f1f1f1'><strong><p>Exercise:</strong> $row->exercise</p>
        <strong><p>Weight:</strong> $row->weight</p>
        <strong><p>Reps:</strong> $row->reps</p>
        <strong><p>Sets:</strong> $row->sets</p>
        <strong><p>notes:</strong> $row->notes</p>
        <strong><p>Date:</strong> $row->date</p>
        <a class='btn btn-success'><i class='fa fa-plus-square m-right-xs'> </i>  View All</a>" 
        ?>
```

Trying to display all entries in db for one person the problem is how do I bind a joined table when I try

```
$count->bindParam(":member_id",$member_workouts.member_id,PDO::PARAM_INT,3);
```

it doesn't work like I would expect.

Basically the code should return all workouts for the member based on his member_id I have it returning the most recent entry to the db but not all and it has me stumped!! I am struggling to find info in google search that I can make sense of.

I am fairly new to php code so I'm learning. constructive criticism is more than welcome.

Comment: 1. you don't need join here. Take out login from query. 2. change fetch() to [fetchAll()](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#fetchall). 3. Follow the link to learn PDO

Comment: I have removed login, now when I change the fetch to fetchAll I get the following error. 'Notice: Trying to get property of non-object'

Comment: You will have to iterate it Steve. Use a loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some field in `member_workouts` with is fk to `login` pk, add condition to `WHERE` or to `ON`.
For example login_id & id, use query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM login
JOIN member_workouts ON member_workouts.login_id = login.id --it is only example
WHERE member_workouts.member_id=:member_id
```

anyway, without join condition you get multiplication of rows.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem with the code below by throwing a while loop in seemed to resolve issue.

```
 <?Php

$handler = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=manager', 'root', ******);
$count=$handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM member_workouts WHERE member_id=:member_id ORDER BY date DESC");
$count->bindParam(":member_id",$member_id,PDO::PARAM_INT,3);

    if($count->execute())

    while($row = $count->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) 


     if( ! $row)
print('<h4>No Workouts Found</h4>'); 


else 


echo    "<tr bgcolor='#f1f1f1'><strong><p>Exercise:</strong> $row->exercise</p>
        <strong><p>Weight:</strong> $row->weight</p>
        <strong><p>Reps:</strong> $row->reps</p>
        <strong><p>Sets:</strong> $row->sets</p>
        <strong><p>notes:</strong> $row->notes</p>
        <strong><p>Date:</strong> $row->date</p>
        <hr>" 
        ?>
```